# Why is my recovery partition content so different than another one I saw?

Tags: operating-systems, recovery-partition

From [this video that I saw](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl_HUKEDzNA) on creating a recovery partition, the contents of his recovery partition was a folder named `WindowsImageBackup`.

The screenshot below is what is inside my recovery partition and this was pre-made when I bought my laptop from HP. Why is this different?

[image: Recovery]

Comment: Each OEM is different, and have different methods for recovering machines. HP uses a key combination on bootup, and restores from a hidden partition on the hard drive. You'll also have made recovery DVDs (which we discussed in your other question).

Comment: This drive will be wiped out once i get a new hdd. How will this affect future recovery if I create a recovery partition on my own?

Comment: That's why you made DVDs :-).

Comment: So you are saying that this drive will be present in DVD?

Comment: Yes. So, before erasing the old drive, do a test of the DVDs by installing to the new drive.

Comment: OK, will kep you informed on this same question if I ever need help

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/479196/what-is-this-in-my-recovery-partition#comment567006_479196) gives a basic answer:

> Each OEM is different, and have different methods for recovering machines. HP uses a key combination on bootup, and restores from a hidden partition on the hard drive.